# Modelling the effect of a cumulative covariate on the probability of entering a final state

Tags: survival, panel-data, econometrics, hazard

I am trying to model a phenomenon whereby individuals graduate to a final state once they cross a threshold for a covariate of interest (covariate is cumulative over time). I would like to identify the value of the covariate where this threshold exists. I have a rough idea of how I'd like to approach this problem. This involves using a panel fixed effects regression. Can you please look at the description of my question and let me know if what I propose is the best way forward? Are there better approaches? If so, can you point me to sources that present such approaches?

I will proceed by providing a fictitious research question that reflects the main features of the actual question I am trying to answer. Suppose we are interested in finding the number of credit hours a college student must earn before being allowed to graduate. Further, suppose we do not have access to documentation that specifies the number of credit hours required to graduate (this information is generally easy to find via the registrar, but suppose we cannot access this information for sake of example). The only information we have is displayed in the table below. `Case` identifies the individual, `T` measures years passed since beginning college,
`Y` is an indicator for whether an individual is a college graduate at a given time period, `A` is the number of credit hours earned each time period, `B` is a cumulative count of the credit hours, and `B_thr16`-`B_thr24` are indicators for whether the individual has accumulated the number of credit hours indicated by the suffix on the variable name.

```
Case   T     Y     A      B   B_thr16  B_thr20  B_thr24
  A    1     0     4      4      0         0         0
  A    2     0     4      8      0         0         0
  A    3     0     4      16     1         0         0
  A    4     0     4      20     1         1         0
  A    5     0     2      22     1         1         0
  A    6     1     4      26     1         1         1

  B    1     0     8      8      0         0         0
  B    2     0     8      16     1         0         0
  B    3     1     8      24     1         1         1

  C    1     0     8      8      0         0         0
  C    2     0     8      16     1         0         0
  C    3     0     8      24     1         1         1
  C    4     1     5      29     1         1         1
```

I am trying to find the most appropriate way to model this phenomenon. My research question is concerned with identifying the threshold for number of credit hours that best predicts whether an individual has graduated college or not. One potential way to estimate this is by running a panel regression with individual-level fixed effects. This can be represented as the following equation where $Y_{i,t}$ is an indicator for whether individual $i$ has graduated at time $t$; $1(B \geq 16)_{i,t}$, $1(B \geq 20)_{i,t}$ and $1(B \geq 24)_{i,t}$ are threshold indicators corresponding to having earned at least 16, 20 and 24 credit hours respectively; $X$ is a vector of control variables; and $\alpha_i$ is an individual FE:

$$Y_{i,t} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 1(B\geq 16)_{i,t} + \beta_2 1(B\geq 20)_{i,t} + \beta_3 1(B\geq 24)_{i,t} + X\gamma+ \alpha_i+ \varepsilon_{i}$$

The intercept and the parameters on the threshold indicators can be combined to predict the probability of graduation at different levels of credit hours. A plot of these predicted probabilities would show whether the probability of graduation "jumps" at  certain thresholds of credit hours. This can also be learned by examining the relative magnitudes of each threshold parameter.

Comment: Have you considered using a survival analysis model to deal with this? The other issue is if you expect the threshold to vary across people.

Comment: I am new to survival analysis and will look into it. Before I begin reading, can you let me know whether survival analysis is still relevant if I am not interested in analyzing time-to-graduation? Instead, I am interested in identifying the value for credit hours (threshold) that is associated with the largest increase in probability of graduation. Is it possible to quickly summarize the benefits of using survival analysis (compared to a fixed effects regression) if my only goal is to identify the threshold?

Comment: From what I can tell, an advantage of survival analysis is that it allows you to deal with censored data. I don't think my data suffers from this issue. There are two types of individuals in my data: (1) those who graduate and thus, have already experienced the event, and (2) those who drop out of college altogether with no intention to return/graduate. My data does not contain individuals who are still enrolled in college and intend to graduate in the future. Given this, would it be fair to conclude that my data does not suffer from the type of censoring that survival models address?

Comment: In other words, I don't believe my data suffers from censoring because we can assume that those who dropped out without graduating will never graduate. This might not seem like a good assumption for this current example which deals with graduating college students. However, it makes sense in the actual process I am trying to model (which deals with a different issue from the graduation example).